# The ratio of speed of man in still water to the speed of the current is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$P,Q,R$ are three towns on a river which flows uniformly. $Q$ is equidistant from $P$ and $R$. A man rows $P$ to $Q$ and back in $10$ hours. He can row from $P$ to $R$ in $4$ hours. The ratio of the speed of the man in still water to the speed of the current is:

My try: For a given distance, rowing downstream takes less time than rowing upstream, so he goes downstream for $2$ hours from $P$ to $Q$ and goes upstream for $8$ hours from $Q$ to $P$.

[image]

I can find ratios of Downstream speed & Upstream speed.

Question is about ratio of speed of man in still water to the speed of the current. So help me out here.

Comment: Image: https://i.imgur.com/RVKLdmg.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Let the speed in still water be $m$ and speed of current be $w$.

While going downstream, time taken will be less since speed would add up, i.e. become $(m+w)$.
From the question and using the fact that $\frac{distance}{time}= speed$, we get $\frac{d}{2}=(m+w)$.

While going downstream, time taken will be less since speed would add up, i.e. become $(m-w)$.
Therefore, $\frac{d}{8}=(m-w)$.

Let the ratio $m/w$ be $r$.
Now, divide the LHS and RHS of above two equations to get this:
$\frac{8}{2}=\frac{(m+w)}{(m-w)}=\frac{(r+1)}{(r-1)}$

Solve for r, which will be your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the first equation be $\frac{d}{2}=(m+w)$?

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz